# Apple Watch hand gesture detection

Tags: ios, apple-watch, gesture

I would like to get the events from Apple Watch, like when watch is wavied or some hand gestures to be detected.

i couldn't find any APIs for this. Can you point me to this gesture detection for Apple Watch...

Answer (score 1):

The Core Motion and Core ML frameworks should lead you in the right direction, and the following WWDC sessions will be helpful:

- [Health and Fitness with Core Motion](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/713/)
- [Building Activity Classification Models in Create ML](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/426/)